# Encapsulate PHP memcache set and get function

Tags: php, static, singleton, memcached

Have this class:

```
class Cacher
{
    private static $memcacheObj = NULL;

    public static function GetInstance()
    {
        if (self::$memcacheObj === NULL) 
        {
            self::$memcacheObj = new Memcache;
            self::$memcacheObj->addServer(Configs::memcache_addr);
        }
        return self::$memcacheObj;
    }

    public static function Set($key, $var, $flag = 0, $expire = 0)
    {
        self::GetInstance()->set($key, $var, 0, $expire);
    }

    public static function Get($key, $flag = 0)
    {
        self::GetInstance()->get($key);
    }
}
```

Using like this, it doesn't work, nothing retrieved from Cacher::Get when refreshing my page:

```
$keyValue = Cacher::Get('key_name');
if(empty($keyValue))
{
    Cacher::Set('key_name', 'key_value', 0, 0);
}
else
{
    echo "Got value : $keyValue";
}
```

However below code will work:

```
$keyValue = Cacher::GetInstance()->get('key_name');
if(empty($keyValue))
{
    Cacher::GetInstance()->set('key_name', 'key_value', 0, 0);
}
else
{
    echo "Got value : $keyValue";
}
```

Could anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning the result in Get. Should be:

```
public static function Get($key, $flag = 0)
{
    return self::GetInstance()->get($key);
}
```

Comment: We all have days where we miss the simple things, god bless SO :)